# The desc order with group by is not working at linq

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the **descending** order of a list then group by of the **descending** list. But I don't know why the query is not working.

```
List<RentBillRegister> result = _dbContextRent.RentBillRegisters.Where(x => x.Month == month && x.BillId != null).OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
            .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId)
            .SelectMany(grouping => grouping.Take(1))
            .ToList();
```

It's returning the group by the result it's not desc the list before grouping. I just need least id when grouping.

Even I just try to see the desc result using this query.

```
 var result = _dbContextRent.RentBillRegisters.Where(x => x.Month == month && x.BillId != null).OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

But also it's returning assending order list. Can  any one explain it?

Comment: I am not able to replicate such behavior,could you look for some other code in your program.

Comment: may be an issue in your EF provider / DBMS. What does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your simple Where - OrderByDescending problem. In my case (Id is an int) the sequence is correctly ordered.

So I concentrated on your first problem.

If seems to me, that you want from your sequence of `RentBillRegisters`, from every used ClientId, the `RentBillRegister` with the highest `Id`.

You do this by first sorting all `RentBillRegisters`, by descending Id; then you Group all `RentBillRegisters` into groups of same `ClientId`, and from every group you take the first element. This is is supposed to be the `RentBillRegister` in that group with the highest Id.

```
Id | ClientId
01 |    A
02 |    B
03 |    A
04 |    A
05 |    C
06 |    B

// After ordering by descending Id: 
[06 B] [05 C] [04 A] [03 A] [02 B] [01 A]

// After grouping by ClientId and from every group take the first
group B: [06 B] [02 B]          => [06 B]
group C: [05 C]                 => [05 C]
group A: [04 A] [03 A] [01 A]   => [04 A]
```

If RentBillRegister A and B will end up in different groups, why would you compare them to order them? Wouldn't it be much more efficient to first group the items, and then order the items within each group?

```
var result = dbContextRent.RentBillRegisters
  .Where(...)

  // make groups of RentBillRegisters that have the same ClientId
  .GroupBy(rentBillRegister => rentBillRegister.ClientId

    // ResultSelector: take the clientId that was selected as key
    // and all rentBillRegisters with this clientId to create a new object
    (clientId, rentBillRegistersWithThisClientId) => 

      // I don't want all RentBillRegisters With This ClientId,
      // I want only the one with the highest Id
      // = the first after sorting by Id in descending order
      // Nota Bene: I don't use the Key (ClientId) anymore
      rentBillRegistersWithThisClientId
        .OrderByDescending(rentBillRegister => rentBillRegister.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault(),
  })

  // now you have from all `RentBillRegisters` with the same clientId the one 
  // with the highest Id. The groups are not ordered yet:
  .OrderByDescending(rentBillRegisterWithHighestId => rentillRegisterWithHighesId.ClientId);
```

From the collections above:

```
// Make Groups with same ClientId, order and take the first
Group  by  ClientId   | After Ordering       | Take First 
Group with ClientId A | [04 A] [03 A] [01 A] | [04 A]
Group with ClientId B | [06 B] [02 B]        | [06 B]
Group with ClientId C | [05 C]               | [05 C]

// Order the groups by descending Id:
[06 B] [05 C] [04 A]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, both ids ware long int.  I want to show all latest bill of each client that's why I try to ordering desc then sort them. Now `.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id) .GroupBy(c => c.ClientId) .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault()) .ToList();` it's working fine for me.

Comment: Tip: next question give a proper requirement. Something like: "I want something like this code, but this code doesn't do what I want", isn't sufficient. Quite often it helps me in my LINQ question to clearly write down what I want: from  my input sequences of ... give me the items that ...

Answer (score 0):

So, I gave it a go and coded the simplest example to try this out and for some reason the OrderByDesc doesnt work with string, probably needs to have a comparer provided to determine which one is bigger than the other. So if you field Id is a string thats the problem. I tried the same example but with integers and it worked as expected.
A simple solution is to convert the ID to int using Convert.ToInt32 inside the orderBy. Of course that only makes sense if the ID contains only numbers, if you have letters in there you will have to sort them using another technique.

Hope this helps!

Code example working:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "5", "2", "1", "10" };

        list.OrderByDescending(item => Convert.ToInt32(item)).ToList().ForEach(itemOrdered => teResult.Text += "  " + itemOrdered.ToString());
```